# pass output as grep pattern

Tags: grep, pipe, io-redirection, xargs, exec

I wish to pass each line of a file as a grep pattern to be searched in data.txt file.

Thus, i need `cat allsearchstrings.txt | grep <should be lines of allsearchstrings.txt> data.txt`

cat allsearchstring

```
: 'CANV'
: 'CANV_MATCH'
: 'MY'
```

I think `xargs` could be the solution but I'm not sure how-to.

Note: the content of allsearchstrings.txt may have single quotes `'`

Could you please suggest?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? `grep` should be able to read patterns from a file directly (with the `-f` option)

Comment: @steeldriver here is the search string `: 'CANV'
: 'CANV_MATCH'
: 'MY'` . Now, if i do `cat allsearchstrings.txt | grep -f data.txt` it does not return any output when the pattern is present in the file as this -> grep ": 'CANVL'" data.txt
CLUSTER_CANV01: 'CANV'`

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it would be `grep -f allsearchstrings.txt data.txt` or `grep -F -f allsearchstrings.txt data.txt` since your search pattern appears to be a fixed string rather than a regular expression

Comment: To elaborate on steeldriver's point, there is no reason to `cat` the file and pipe it into `grep` as the latter can use the filename as an argument via the `-f` switch. Your question states that you want each line of `allsearchstrings.txt` to be used as the regex to return strings lines from `data.txt`. A simple `grep -fF allsearchstrings.txt data.txt` will do.

Comment: It not a file but output of some complex command which i wanted to avoid sharing.

Comment: ... in that case you can try `complex_command | grep -F -f - data.txt` or `grep -F -f <(complex_command) data.txt` if your shell supports process substitution

Comment: @steeldriver that worked !! can u post it as an answer please

Comment: If it's not a file but command output, then in the future, be clear about what it is instead of stating `I wish to pass each line of a file as a grep pattern` and using `cat allsearchstrings.txt` as an example. That doesn't line up with what's actually going on and makes it more difficult for people to answer your question.

Comment: @steeldriver yes, it answers my question

Comment: try the following:

for x in $(cat allsearchstrings.txt); do grep $x data.txt; done